# AngularJS with MVC Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

We have an existing/legacy MVC 5 application and would like to 'experiment' with some AngularJS SPA within the main application.

To keep this clean and separate, we have created a new MVC Area  (the application already uses Areas) with the following default controller...

```
namespace Acme.WebAdmin.Areas.Scheduler.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController 
       : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult PageOne()
        {
           return PartialView();
        }

        public ActionResult PageTwo()
        {
           return PartialView();
        }

        public ActionResult PageThree()
        {
           return PartialView();
        }
    }
}
```

The SchedulerAreasRegistration.cs file looks like this:

```
public class SchedulerAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Scheduler";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Scheduler_default",
            "Scheduler/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new
            {
               controller = "Home",
               action = "Index", 
               id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
    }
}
```

On the /Scheduler/Home/Index View we have the following HTML:

```
<div ng-app="SchedulerApp" ng-controller="ManagementPageController">


   <p>{{models.helloAngular}}</p>

   <ul>
        <li><a href="/#/PageOne">PageOne</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/PageTwo">PageTwo</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/PageThree">PageThree</a></li>
    </ul>

   <div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

We have also added the route dependency to the AngularJS application:

```
var SchedulerApp = angular.module('SchedulerApp', ['ngRoute']);

SchedulerApp.controller('ManagementPageController', ManagementPageController);

var configFunction = function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $routeProvider.
       when('/PageOne', {
          templateUrl: 'Home/PageOne'
       })
       .when('/PageTwo', {
          templateUrl: 'Home/PageTwo'
       })
       .when('/PageThree', {
          templateUrl: 'Home/PageThree'
       });

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
configFunction.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];

SchedulerApp.config(configFunction);
```

When we run the app and click on the navigation links (e.g. 'PageTwo') I always get returned to the standard web site home page with the following URL http://localhost:52654/#/PageTwo.

I am not sure if the problem is AngualrJS not intercepting the reference, of if it is a MVC routing problem.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the area in templateUrl `Scheduler/Home/PageOne`.

Comment: I tried that, but I still get redirected back to the 'true' home page e.g. http://localhost:52654/#/PageOne - it almost seems that Angular is not intercepting the request (I assume that is what it does) as it actually just redirects to the stated href='/#/PageOne'.  I am not seeing any JavaScript errors on the page.

Comment: What does your MVC routing rules look like for the root level and for your area?

Comment: I have added the SchedulerAreaRegistration.cs content to the original question - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using improper href syntax with extra leading `/`.

A leading `/` on any relative url will look for base root. Thus all you are doing is reloading the page each time

Change

```
<a href="/#/PageTwo">PageTwo</a>
```

TO

```
<a href="#/PageTwo">PageTwo</a>
```

All you want is a hash in href, then angular path is everything after the `#`

Comment: I have modified the code as suggested, but the instead of redirecting to the web site's home page (as you predicted), the AngularJS page remains loaded but the ng-view placeholder does not populate.

Comment: When I modified the HTML, I didn't immediately notice that a JavaScript error was now being thrown on the $locationProvider injection.  When I removed this and changed the templateUrl references to just the name of the view (e.g. 'PageOne') the page routed correctly.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: possibly paths to templates aren't correct? Need to look in browser dev tools for console errors and on netwrok tab to see what happens with any requests